# Android studio error solving using logcat newer version

Tags: android, logcat

How to solve error in new version of  android studio  using logcat

Explain with easiest way expecting i am a beginner . Expalin with easiest way so that i understand.I  am  a beginner and tutorial is available for previous version android studio

Comment: Sorry but you give us way too less details to be able to help you. Please edit your question a d describe in detail what error get. Copy the full error as text into your question.